# Selling Asset to Own Company and Recording as Directors Loan

Tags: united-kingdom, accounting, limited-liability-company

So I've set up a limited company (in England and Wales) and I want to sell some of the equipment I bought for this company prior to incorporation so that I can claim back the VAT.

However, there's not enough money in the business at the moment to actually pay me for these so I want to just record this as being paid into my director's loan account.

How would I go about recording this properly?

I use Sage Business Cloud so specific advice would be great.